# Merge using threads not working in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have to merge two lists and every time a full the lists in order to merge them , but what is happening that I did it like this :

```
   def repeated_fill_buffer(self):
        """
      repeat the operation until reaching the end of file
        """
        # clear buffers from last data
        self.block = [[] for file in self.files]

        filling_buffer_thread = threading.Thread(self.fill_buffer())
        filling_buffer_thread.start()

        # create inverted index thread
        create_inverted_index_thread = threading.Thread(self.create_inverted_index())
        create_inverted_index_thread.start()

        # check if buffers are not empty to merge and start the thread
        if any(self.block):
            self.block = [[] for file in self.files]
            filling_buffer_thread.join()
            create_inverted_index_thread.join()
```

but what is happening that `filling_buffer_thread` and `create_inverted_index_thread` just called one time, and not working again, when I debugged the code I see that

> filling_buffer_thread stopped

I don't know if I explain my question good, but what I want that I can called same thread multi time and run them..

Comment: thread needs function's name without `()` - (it is called `callback`) - `Thread(target=self.fill_buffer)` - and later it will use `()` to run this function.

Comment: if one function depends on data from other function then using threads is useless.

Comment: if thread was stopped then you can't start it again but you have to create new thread.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas can u please write it in answer ? so I can tracked it easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is any operation which is CPU Bound then, using thread is of no use. Because of Python GIL, which prevents multiple byte-code instruction to be executed at a time. use multiprocessing module since, every process has its own GIL.

> All number crunching or any operations which depends on CPU for its completion are CPU-Bound. Threads are  useful for I/O Bound Operations (like Database Calls, Network Calls)

To summarize your error, `your filling_buffer_thread` got blocked due to `create_inverted_index_thread`